# PyCharm debugger "fails to find a free socket port" when attempting to debug a simple program

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm trying to debug a Python program using PyCharm, but it fails, saying `Error Running 'filename': Failed to find a free socket port.`

The code I'm trying to debug (finding prime numbers):

```
lower = int(input("minnumber: "))
upper = int(input("maxnumber: "))

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    # initialize sum
    sum = 0
    # exponent
    n = len(str(num))

    # test
    temp = num
    while temp > 0:
        digit = temp % 10
        sum += digit ** n
        temp //= 10

    if num == sum:
        print(num)
```

[Here's what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkAYn.png), and [this is the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tutDh.png) for the debugger.

I'm using Windows 10 with Pycharm version 2019.3.3.

Comment: Debugger frontend communicates with the backend over a socket, seems like it can't find an open port on your machine. Check your firewall/antivirus settings, perhaps it blocks IDE.

Comment: It smmes blocked by antivirus.Problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: The way, how it was solved is missing. Please add what you have done.